# How can I make git treat symlinks as a file?

Tags: linux, symlink, git

I have a very specific use case. The DesignSync versioning system we use replaces files with their symlink to the remote repository when we check-in a file.

Since I use git locally to version my changes before checking it in, I don't want "*replacing a file with a symlink*" or vice versa to be considered a change in the file - as long as the content of the file/symlink is the same.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a "beautiful" way forward here, aside from moving away from that symlink methodology (I don't know whether that's a feature DesignSync has. You might need to hope Dassault sees the errors in its ways.) You're just trying to use two different code versioning tools, with contradicting approaches, and it seems logically impossible to me to reconcile these two perfectly.

You *need* to use git on the actual files – otherwise, it won't see any changes when you change the contents. You *need* to respect DesignSyncs symlinking.

There's three ways I saw, but I tried and can rule out the first:

- <s>Using .gitattributes, you could have a "smudge" and a "clean" filter that replace symlinks with the files symlinked to, and vice versa, on commit and checkout.</s> Doesn't work, since symlinks get no special treatment in .gitattributes
- You can write a pre-commit script that looks to replace all symlinks with the original files, copied from the DesignSync-managed "upstream".
- You could write a FUSE file system that gives you a second "view" at the DesignSync repository, in which the symlinks get replaced by the actual files symlinked to. You bind-mount in a .git repository directory and manage your files in git that way.

Neither way is going to be painless. I'll be honest, you'll have to pick *one* source control system to use at a time; what you're trying to do just makes me feel uneasy.

I honestly think the easiest way might be to not do anything special – keep your local git repository as is, and have a separate checkout whenever you feel like checking in changed files to DesignSync. Git can check out your repository into arbitrary locations! Whenever you need to pull in changes from DesignSync into your git repository, I'd honestly just `cp -L` ("following" the symlinks) a fresh DesignSync checkout into your git repo.

Comment: Note that the last option, FUSE filesystem to resolve symlinks, already exists. Use bindfs (https://bindfs.org/) with resolve-symlinks flag. It is available in most modern OS repos.